# Programatically get the webform submission "sid" on submitForm

Tags: 8, webforms

I am trying to programatically get the webform submission sid on submitting a webform but failed to get it !

On my **customwebformhandler.php** file i have the below:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
// Get an array of the values from the submission.
    $values = $webform_submission->getData();

    // Get the Webform submission "Sid".
    $sid = $webform_submission->id();

// Show a success message.
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t("$sid"));    

}
```

but i am not getting any sid value.

any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out i will have to save the webform before i can get its sid since i am using the `public function submitForm` which is fire in submitting the webform but before saving it.

**Final code will be:**

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
// Get an array of the values from the submission.
    $values = $webform_submission->getData();
    // ...
    $webform_submission->save();

    // Get the Webform submission "Sid" after saving the webform submission.
    $sid = $webform_submission->id();

// Show a success message.
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t("$sid"));    

}
```